Prepositions can really change the meaning
I think that prepositions can really change the meaning of a sentence. I'd like to check if I'm right.

When I hit her (for 2 minutes) she cried

To me 1 without "for 2 minutes" means that she starts crying after I hit her. On the other hand with "for 2 minutes" it changes the meaning and the new meaning is that during my hitting she cried.
Is that Correct?

When I cooked (in 40 minutes) she arrived

Without "in 40 minutes" she for sure arrived during the time I was cooking. Again, I think that with "in 40 minutes" the sentence implies that she arrived once I was done with cooking after 40 minutes. Is that Correct?

Sentence 1: I'm not happy to discuss the right way to talk about hitting a woman. Sentence 2: Based on your own notes we would use while, not when to describe "during the time..." While I was cooking, she arrived. For the 40 minute example: When (or After) I had been cooking for 40 minutes, she arrived.

Sentence 1 is totally unidiomatic. To hit something is a single action, so to get your intended meaning you would need to say something like "When I hit her repeatedly for two minutes she began to cry." (Agree with Peter that it's a horrible sentence.)

@KateBunting what about my 2 example?

Again, unidiomatic. A native speaker would say something like "She arrived while I was cooking dinner/baking a cake".  With the time phrase - "I had been cooking for 40 minutes when she arrived".

@KateBunting I use "in" not "for" in my 2 example. I believe they have different meanings. I think "in" shows completion. That's why I think my 2 example means after I was done with the cooking in 40 minutes she arrived after not during my cooking?

"She arrived 40 minutes after I'd finished cooking".

@KateBunting "when I painted my room in 3 hours she arrived". Could you please tell me if it means that she arrived during the painting or once it was done. I have no more questions. Thanks, please answer.

As it stands, it doesn't mean anything. How many times do we have to tell you that this kind of thing isn't helpful to you? If the painting was ongoing, it doesn't make sense to say that 'in three hours she arrived' - three hours after what? If it was finished, you would say 'after I had painted my room' (or 'finished painting').

@KateBunting  I meant "when I painted my room in three hours,     she arrived". "In 3 hours" refers to painting not her arriving. That it took  me three hour to paint the room.

You wouldn't say it like that. "It took me three hours to paint my room, and she arrived while I was doing it/when I had finished."

Semantically, "When I painted my room in three hours, she arrived" is just stupid, but syntactically it's fine. Compare "When he ran a mile in 5 minutes, she congratulated him", which is a perfectly reasonable utterance. As with so many questions from this OP, the example sentences are pointlessly weird.

I agree that example 1 is horrible.  The theme distracts users and hence affects their analysis of the grammar.  Let's change it to When I tickled her (for 2 minutes) she laughed.

Consider When he was given a sedative, he calmed down in a few minutes, which is easy to understand. Whereas When he was given a sedative, he calmed down for a few minutes is syntactically fine, but requires a bit of head-scratching to imagine a context where it would make sense. And as ever, context is everything.

What's so horrible about my 1 example. It is just a sentence. I have never hit anyone.

It seems odd to choose a sentence about violence as one of your examples.

@user203412: can you not see the difference between When I ran a mile (in 5 minutes) she cheered (natural phrasing for an easily-understood context) and When I cooked (in 40 minutes) she arrived (same syntax, but completely meaningless to me)?

While there can be profound writing about horrible things, as long as we're making up abstract examples, there's no need to make people think about them. Works like The Color Purple, A Streetcar Named Desire, or Schindler's List process their atrocities to say something ultimately beautiful about the human experience (or that's the idea anyway). This isn't the place or the scope for that, so it's just unnecessary unpleasantness, and that's not nice.

@user203412 Domestic violence is a major issue and your sentence looks horrible because of the pronoun "I". I suggest you change it to "he hit her" or   "he hit me". Sometimes violence against women turns dangerous and it should be reported to the police. Changing the pronouns would help.

"when I painted my room in 3 hours" does not express a point in time. It is an occasion not bound to a timeline and it cannot serve to indicate when something else happened.

Do you remember that time I painted the whole house in one day?

"She arrived when I painted the whole house in one day" is nonsensical.
But this would work:

She arrived on the day you ran a mile in under four minutes for the first time.

"on the day you ran a mile in under four minutes for the first time" establishes a point-in-time on a timeline.
Replacing "on the day" with "when" takes the sentence towards nonsense:

She arrived when you ran a mile in under four minutes for the first time.

Removing "for the first time" takes it into the heart of nonsense:

She arrived when you ran a mile in under four minutes.

The phrase "when you ran a mile in under four minutes" expresses an achievement.
Achievements are atemporal.
They can be linked to a timeline with a phrase like "for the first time". They can also be linked to a timeline contextually:

Do you remember that time I painted the whole house in one day?

But absent such linkage they cannot serve to mark when something else happened.

You're focused on the words "in" vs "for" and asking them to imply something about the order of events, but the real problem is that you're asking to much of the word "when." "When" is not a very precise word about timing. It does imply response —"when X happened, Y happened," so it's hard to find a meaning in which Y comes before X—but aside from that, many timings are possible:

"Go for a walk when it's sunny": "when" means "during [the time that]."
"Start swimming when you hear the starting tone": "when" means "at the same time, or actually immediately after since that's how reactions work, probably only microseconds after."
"I'll watch that movie when it's released on streaming video": "when" means "a reasonable and vague amount of time after; maybe the day it's released, maybe a week, maybe a few months."
"Drink when you're thirsty": "when" actually means "whenever"; that is, drink any time that the condition is met.

Meanwhile, many of your questions are about formulas rather than meanings. I've given you this answer before, but I'll give it again: Not all formulas work for all meanings, and you can't plug just any word into a pattern and expect it to work idiomatically. Many comments and answers have pointed out that "when I cooked in 40 minutes she arrived" isn't a reasonable sentence with a clear meaning. "When I ran a marathon in 5 hours she cheered" is. But it doesn't say anything clearly about whether the running and the cheering were simultaneous, or if not, how much time was in between.
I encourage you in the future, when curious about a tense or a phrase, to find an example in "real writing," a book or article or so on, instead of creating an artificial example; then, we can talk about how the context affects the meaning.

I. OP's first sentence and intended meanings:

When I hit her (for 2 minutes) she cried.
'1. To me 1 without "for 2 minutes" means that she starts crying after I hit her.
'2. On the other hand with "for 2 minutes" it changes the meaning and the new meaning is that during my hitting she cried. Is that Correct?

To convey your first intended meaning clearly, the sentence should be rephrased:
'1. She started crying after he had been hitting her for 2 minutes.
To convey the second meaning you should rephrase the sentence as.
'2. For 2 minutes, he was hitting her and she was crying.".
Or.
'"For 2 minutes, he was hitting her continuously, and she was crying."
II. OP's second sentence and intended meaning:

When I cooked (in 40 minutes) she arrived.
'3. Without "in 40 minutes" she for sure arrived during the time I was cooking.
4. Again, I think that with "in 40 minutes" the sentence implies that she arrived once I was done with cooking after 40 minutes. Is that Correct?

No, the sentences don't convey the intended meaning: Sentence 3 should be rephrased as:
'3. I had been cooking for 40 minutes when she arrived. (implies she arrived during cooking.)
To clearly convey the cooking time and its completion Sentence 4 should be rephrased as
The cooking was done in 40 minutes before she arrived.
By the time she arrived, I did the cooking in 40 minutes.
(implies she arrived after completion).
Note:.
Domestic violence is a major issue and your sentence looks horrible because of the pronoun "I". I suggest you change it to "he hit her" or "he hit me".
Sometimes violence against women turns dangerous and it should be reported to the police. Changing the pronouns would help.

Using 'for' does not imply during.  It could mean that for example, she cried after you hit her for two minutes, but not if you hit for a shorter period.
To denote during, you really need to use 'while'
For instance

While I was hitting her for two minutes, she cried.
While I was cooking, for 40 minutes, she arrived.


what about my second example?
